# Mongoose: How to use data from a schema (product value) to populate a field in another schema () using a method?

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Is it possible to use values within a schema that came from another Schema to fulfill the requirements of a new document?

I have two schemas; the first one is called Products and the second one is called Orders.

Products Schema has two fields:

1. name (String)
2. price (number).

models/products.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   price: {type: Number}
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)
```

Orders Schema has two fields too:

1. products_ids which are an array of ObjectId of products [ObjectId]
2. total_price which should be the sum of all the products prices.

models/order.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Product = mongoose.model('Product')

var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  product_id: [{type:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}],
  total_price: getTotal(this.product_id)
})

function getTotal(arrId){

  if (arrId.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  let totalPrice = 0

 arrId.forEach((id) => {
   let prod = new Product()
   prod.findById(id, (product)=>{
    totalPrice += product.price
   })
  })  
  return totalPrice;
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema)
```

this last field (total_price) is causing me troubles because I want to create a method which iterates through all the values in “this.products_ids.” array and automatically returns the sum of all the prices

the error that I am getting is the following:
“Schema hasn’t been registered for model “Product”.”

Is there a work around of this? Can I do what I think here or should I calculate the sum of the product’s price outside of my model?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.pre` function. for example in your code:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Product = mongoose.model('Product')

var orderSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    product_id: [{type:  mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Product'}],
    total_price: {type: Number, default:0}
})
orderSchema.pre('save', getTotal (next) {
    let order = this;
  if (arrId.length === 0) {
    return 0;
  }

  let totalPrice = 0

 arrId.forEach((id) => {
   let prod = new Product()
   prod.findById(id, (product)=>{
    totalPrice += product.price
   })
  })  
  order.total_price= totalPrice;

});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Order', orderSchema)
```